# Why is there a minimum distance to a corner from a direct vent exhaust?

Tags: furnace

According to the instructions for my direct vent furnace, (item #4) the minimum distance from the center of the vent to the nearest corner is 16 inches. Why is that important?

I understand the minimum distance to a window/door, but this one makes no sense to me.

[image]

Comment: Maybe they mean an inside corner? I was thinking an outside corner. Inside would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Item #4 is referring to turbulence.

Wind does not blow smoothly past a building. It will twist and curl on the leeward side. This curling effect could “push” air back the wrong direction near the corners of buildings.